# Why can't I set max-width of an image without resizing

Tags: html, css, image

I have an `img` in a container. I have given the image `width: 100%` and now I want to set a `max-height` for the image without resizing it.

I tried adding `max-height: 120px; overflow: hidden;` but it is not working.

Why can't I crop the image to be 100% width and 120px height from top?

**Demo:**

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/14727/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <img src="http://www.tuning-links.com/uploads/image/2009/June/VW%20Scirocco%20Remis/VW_Scirocco_Remis_4.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <img src="http://www.tuning-links.com/uploads/image/2009/June/VW%20Scirocco%20Remis/VW_Scirocco_Remis_4.jpg" alt="">        
    </div>               
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
img{
    width:100%;
    max-height:120px;
    overflow:hidden;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to wrap the image in a div. Use the same css on a div and it should work.

Comment: I have edited my comment. Try to wrap your image in a div.

Comment: where is jsfiddle link :D

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you set the max-height to 120px it's not going to go over that, which is why the image is resizing. I'm not too sure what you're looking for here?

This may help you out: https://jsfiddle.net/uxp1cbto/

```
img 
{
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: No no man, i want to display image width 100%, and height to be 120px from top, only 120px, not full height

Comment: That's exactly what you've got. Your image width is 100% and the height is 120px. I still don't understand?

Comment: You can try this https://jsfiddle.net/jodhagLd/. If that's still not what you're looking for you'll need to make your goal a little bit more clear :-)

Comment: yes but in my case image is distorted like image 1, I wan't to display like image 2 
http://i.imgur.com/oUv5qtt.png

Comment: On image 2 the height is not set to max 120px. If you want the height to be a maximum of 120px that's fine, but the width will be smaller. Like so: https://jsfiddle.net/jodhagLd/1/

Comment: If you're setting the image to a width of 100% it's going to be the size of the element it resides within. Thus, if you add a max-height of 120px the width will be 100% while the max-height is 120px and that's what causes the image to distort.

Comment: but i want to display image in thats containter which 120 px and width 100% , to be similar liek image 2

Comment: If you want to cut the image then do this https://jsfiddle.net/jodhagLd/2/. I've set the example as 360px but you can set it to whatever you want :-)